# C++ ofstream will not open file

Tags: c++, file

I cannot open a file with ostream. The file will create. When I check the perms for the file the file does not have modify permission but it has write/read perm. Not sure if that means anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writeFile(string name) {
    ofstream myfile(name.c_str()); // create file
    myfile.open(name.c_str(), ios::app);
    if (myfile) {
    myfile << "a \n";
    } else {
        cout << "failed to open\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
}

int main() {
writeFile("output.txt");
}
```

Comment: While this is not the greatest question ever posted, I'm interested why someone voted to close it as "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." - it certainly is about programming within that scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
 ofstream myfile(name.c_str());
```

opens the file. Then this:

```
 myfile.open(name.c_str(), ios::app);
```

attempts to open it again. You want:

```
 ofstream myfile(name.c_str(), ios::app );
```

and forget the call to `open()`.